# Time things with Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

How can i time how much time passes between 2 events with javascript? like, to the millisecond?

Comment: It's worth noting that the accuracy of Javascript timing can be pretty questionable, both in terms of async code (setTimeout, setInterval) and in terms of polling duration (as with the answers given here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's surprisingly difficult to do.

```
var start = new Date();
// Do things here
var finish = new Date();
var difference = new Date();
difference.setTime(finish.getTime() - start.getTime());
alert( difference.getMilliseconds() );
```

Comment: If you just want the milliseconds, of course, you don't need to create a new date—you just subtract the two times. Also, you can shorten lines 4-5 into: var difference = new Date(finish.getTime() - start.getTime());

Comment: Oh for the love of ramen. If you have more than 999 milliseconds, this method will not work at all.

Answer (score 16):

When performing arithmetic operations on `Date` objects, they are implicitly converted to milliseconds (since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), so all you need to do is subtract a `Date` created when the operation started from a `Date` created when the operation ends.

```
var start = new Date();
doSomeHeavyWork();
var end = new Date();
var millisecondsElapsed = end - start;
```

Answer (score 15):

Easiest way to do this.

```
console.time("timer name")
console.timeEnd("timer name")
```

This will output the time in milliseconds to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (firefox plugin) to benchmark your functions. Check this article : [benchmark javascript funcions](http://www.answerbag.com/articles/How-to-Execute-JavaScript-With-Firebug/4e7b48b3-65b7-a029-00ca-6a83a45a99fb)

Comment: You can similarly use the Web Inspector in Safari and Chrome (and other WebKit browsers). The results in these tools will be more reliable and provide more information than manual Date polling.

Answer (score 2):

What about making a reusable timer object?

Usage:

```
// event 1
document.getElementById('elId').onclick = function () {
  timer.start('myTimer1');
};

// event 2
document.getElementById('otherElement').onclick = function () {
  alert(timer.stop('myTimer1')); // alerts the time difference in ms
};
```

Implementation:

```
var timer = (function () {
  var startTimes = {}; // multiple start times will be stored here

  return {
    start: function (id) {
      id = id || 'default'; // set id = 'default' if no valid argument passed
      startTimes[id] = +new Date; // store the current time using the timer id
    },
    stop: function (id) {
      id = id || 'default';
      var diff = (+new Date - startTimes[id]); // get the difference
      delete startTimes[id]; // remove the stored start time
      return diff || undefined; // return the difference in milliseconds
    }
  };
}());
```

Comment: Awesome, this piece of code works perfectly for the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var initialTime = (new Date).getTime(), i = 55000;

(function() {
    while ( i-- ) {
        setTimeout( function(){}, 20 );
    }
})()

var finalTime = ( new Date ).getTime(), diff = (new Date);

diff.setTime( finalTime - initialTime );

alert( diff.getMilliseconds() + 'ms' )
```